# How to allow students to work off-line, while still using an LMS to collect work?

Tags: online-learning, homework, technology, learning-management-system

Due to Covid-19, I am having to switch to a "hybrid" format, where I see students less often each week, in smaller groups, and more assignments are pushed on-line. The school is in an extremely rural reservation, where those students who live off-campus are unlikely to have running water, electricity, and internet access. Students are issued Windows laptops.

The current solution is to create assignments in Word, have students download them on campus, work on them at home, then upload the assignments when they are next on campus. I am trying to find a more sophisticated solution for "syncing" their work though, as this step makes it much more time-consuming to grade work. With an LMS, I can post multiple-choice quizzes and other types of interactive assignments, e.g. videos they watch and respond to. Is there some technology that allows for students to save specific LMS pages locally, work on it off-line at home, then when they return to school, they can easily submit? I know students could just leave the browser window open and put the computer to sleep, but that seems risky and students could lose their work.

Comment: Yes, this is surely a world-wide issue. As a small point: if everyone had a USB "sticks" (and computers that could read them!), they could back things up to that, in both directions (to and from physical school). Wouldn't need very big USB's... By now, these are pretty cheap.

Comment: Technically very feasible, but it may not be yet productized. In the simplest case you just use git, but that is likely out of reach on a technical competency level (it is an advanced tool). But something can be done on top of it. Look at DataLad which runs on top of github service

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use git to synchronize documents.

If assignments are provided as simple text documents, they are easily readable on all sorts of devices, and when printed can easily be understood, they can be edited with very low levels of computer hardware and do not require many resources. They can easily be edited with something even as simple as an alpha smart or electronic typewriter! Word Documetns will work with this scheme but it makes the storage requirements (on your side) larger and harder to manage

When at school, a student uses git to "clone" the asignment repository.

When they go home they then work in their own sandbox, and are free to save ("commit")  intermediate versions, locally, on their computer, as many times as you want. They can start from scratch if they wish multiple times without affecting the integrity of the assignment and their other attempts.

When they return to school, the student "pushes" the assignment project to their personal repository. You can review their work and can even examine intermediate versions that show their work and thinking,

The commits have timestamps so you can verify assignment, test, and quiz submission times! (This can be "hacked" but it requires cheating behavior and intentional circumvention)

This is very reminiscent of what we I used for CS courses in University, all of our coding assignments were submitted through a UNIX shell

There are many services that provide Git for free or low cost, Github from microsoft, atllasian bitbucket, and gitlab are common examples.

They can also be deployed , for free, by your school IT on any available server infrastructure.

In a pinch, the students can even synchronize directly to your laptop or other computer, that is, not requiring ANY LMS infrastructure...

Students can even synchronize to/from another student, i.e. you can submit assignments for others and distribute assignments as well, so students who cannot make it physically to school can still get the assignments from their peers. While retaining integrity of the assignments and solutions

There is a significant training challenge, but the tradeoffs are worth it, and the solution is Free, free as in no cost, and free as in freedom (see free software)

Comment: Such skills may be basic for survival in the future...

Comment: @paulgarrett I am willing to consult, pro bono with any educator who needs help implementing this or provide training.

Comment: Does this do quizzes such that as they get a question correct it goes to the next or if wrong it repeats with a similar question to aid the learning process?

Comment: @SolarMike, the use case here are students in rural environments without any infrastructure, the immediate challenge is getting them asignments and getting them back, this system can be scaled by each institutions as needed, commit hooks can automatically grade assignments if needed.

Answer (score 0):

My institution uses Moodle and it does all you need (imho)

You can have things (files, videos, presentations) to be downloaded and they can't download part 2 unless they have downloaded part 1 or submitted part 1. Which means they can log in, download and then log out. It is not tied to one computer but any machine as long as they have their login and password.

Quizzes, I do practice quizzes and quizzes for assessment - categories with types of questions and you can set levels and more.

You can have a forum where they post a question and you can answer or if a student knows the answer then they can respond.

So much - worth checking out and Moodle is not the only one...
But have a look: https://moodle.org/

Comment: Can students, for example, come to campus, download the quiz (plus other assignments for the week), go home, work on the quiz and assignments, then return and be able to submit that work in Moodle that had been done when Internet access wasn't available?

Comment: Is it truly stable off-line? As you know, some things seem to need an internet connection to work at all. I'd be happy to believe it, for many reasons, but ... have some natural skepticism.

Comment: @Village I have not done quizzes in the off-line mode but it is there (just checked) and they need the mobile app, but submitting files is possible. One thing I do for many of my exercises (I teach Excel) is to create self-correcting questions so if the result or formulae is correct then it marks it as correct and keeps a total score.

Comment: @paulgarrett once you have downloaded a word doc, pdf or in my case an excel file then the internet connection is not needed until you want to submit or get something else... And yes, I have students in 90 odd countries with varying internet performance... so they have tested things for me...

Comment: @crasic Well, you are not using it and you are not one of my students who use it for not only my subject but for all their subjects. The syllabi, SoW's and all instructions down to each week are available and our feedback from the students themselves is that the support we have given with all types of material, especially in these times, has been fantastic. One benefit for us is that Moodle has been a resource that we have developed and worked with over the last 10 years, improving and refining what is offered each semester, of course, this semester needed a step change...

Comment: @crasic well we have already had the training for moodle and most is already working and available, you seem to suggest that git needs a significant amount of training, which as the students need it and are using it now would be a significant downtime that is not advisable...

Comment: @crasic a comment I could point at you... No, just a user of moodle. If I had a vested interest it would be mentioned on my profile... Yours seems to mention little.

Comment: @crasic paid nothing and, as always I find RTFM very effective.

Comment: Moodle is a free open-source learning system released under the GNU General Public License and written in PHP, so there's no vendor lock-in, unlike even using Excel or Word.  The UK Open University has 200k users; UK Civil Service 500k users."Previously, the offline capability in Moodle Mobile only extended to quizzes and SCORM. Now learners can also private message other users, add a course note, complete a survey, create a new forum post or new wiki page and even complete an assignment offline." https://moodle.com/news/online-learning-can-access-offline-welcome-moodle-mobile-3-1-3/

Comment: The "private message other users" is offline - the messages are stored and forwarded when connectivity is available, like mailboxes, not like a web forum.

Comment: @Owain I got that, but I don’t think others read it so well...

Comment: The intent here is to advance academic opportunity in rural communities, I am sorry for escalating this discussion and have deleted my comments. For what it is worth I did not downvote your answer